# ctrl-k mapping does not work (but h,j,l does)

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I have the following mappings in my `vimrc`:

```
" -- J
:nmap <C-j> }
:imap <C-j>  <C-O>j
:vmap <C-j> }

" -- K (currently not working??)
:nmap <C-k> {
:imap <C-k> <C-o>k
:vmap <C-k> {
```

The `ctrl-j` mapping works, but the `ctrl-k` mapping does not. I've confirmed that the mappings are there when I do `:verbose map <C-k>`:

```
v  <C-K>         {
    Last set from ~/.vim/vimrc line 113
n  <C-K>         {
    Last set from ~/.vim/vimrc line 111
```

Why does the `j` work, but not the `k`?